# Angular 2 DataTables not working

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, angular2-template

I have a DataTables instance in my list page, and here is my code for them:

```
<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns" >
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

but i get this as a result:

```
<table _ngcontent-c1="" class="table campaign-table dataTable no-footer" datatable="" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
    <thead _ngcontent-c1="" class="thead-default">
        <tr _ngcontent-c1="" role="row"><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Status: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 170px;">Status</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Campaign: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 241px;">Campaign</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 236px;">Start Date</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="End Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 223px;">End Date</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody _ngcontent-c1="">
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
        </tr><tr _ngcontent-c1="">
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty">No data available in table</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

the problem is that the datatables functionality does not work even if the rows are showing the pagination is not working all functionalities are not working...

however when i try this code:

```
<tr  *ngFor="let index of [0,1,2,3,4,5]" >
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

all functionalities works and i get this as a result:

```
<table _ngcontent-c1="" class="table campaign-table dataTable no-footer" datatable="" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
    <thead _ngcontent-c1="" class="thead-default">
        <tr _ngcontent-c1="" role="row"><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Status: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 170px;">Status</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Campaign: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 241px;">Campaign</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 236px;">Start Date</th><th _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="End Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 223px;">End Date</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody _ngcontent-c1="">
        <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "0,1,2,3,4,5"
}-->
    <tr _ngcontent-c1="" role="row" class="odd">
            <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting_1"></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
        </tr><tr _ngcontent-c1="" role="row" class="even">
            <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="sorting_1"></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
            <td _ngcontent-c1=""></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

this is the data that is in the campaign variable:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you create a plnkr?